# dataTables plugin: how to sort data initially (server-side processing)

Tags: datatables

I cannot make it to work properly.

I need on initial load to have my table sorted by 0-index column in 'desc'.
I've tried:

```
$(function() {
    ordersTable = $('#orders').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": 'full_numbers',
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true, 
        "sAjaxSource": "{% url get_orders %}",
        "aoColumnDefs":[
                         {"aTargets":[0], "asSorting": ["decs", "asc"]}
                                 ]
    });
```

and what it does is sends "sSortDir_0 :'asc'" and displaying "asc" active after that.

How can it make it work? (without faking click on the column to resend the ajax)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess I've found it: `aaSorting` and `aaSortingFixed` sets the initial sorting. (reference [here](http://datatables.net/ref#aaSorting))